# Error while using symfony process / exec / shell_exec to launch gcloud compute ssh

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, shell-exec

I need to execute a gcloud coumpute ssh --command via php (I'll check on security later).

Whether I use exec, shell_exec or Symfony Process, the command crashes:

Example with Symfony process (same goes with exec or shell_exec), simple `ls`command used for testing:

```
$process = new Process("/path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute ssh my-instance --command='ls' ");
$process->run();
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
echo $process->getOutput();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {

}
```

I am getting the following error :

> gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Please note that the same command, copied-pasted directly in CLI, works perfectly.

Any hint please ?

Comment: I don't think this will be done, ssh to the instance require ssh key pair, interaction with the metadata server, and the gcloud command to be installed and authenticated.

Comment: Gcloud is of course installed, and authenticated system-wide. Everything works fine hen command is executed directly in CLI. Same command fails with shell_exec. After loads of debuging, looks like PATH env is empty with shell_exec.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation to what happening, $_ENV does not actually set an environment variable, i.e. the variable will not propagate to any child processes you launch (except forked script processes, in which case it's just a variable in the script's memory)
This explanaed [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php#98113).